# Toggling a class in Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am new to Next.js and the React framework. I wanted to ask how to toggle a class.

Here is what I'm trying to do in plain JS:

```js
function toggleNav() {
    var element = document.getElementById("nav");
    element.classList.toggle("hidden");
    element.classList.toggle("flex")
    element.classList.toggle("bg-slate-900")

    var toggler = document.getElementById("toggleNav");
    toggler.classList.toggle("false");
    toggler.classList.toggle("rotate-180");
}
```

I'm using Next.js with TailwindCSS.

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66992178/how-can-i-toggle-a-class-and-change-the-css-in-nextjs

Answer (score 0):

You should learn React.

In React we can't target the element directly, you can use  `useRef()` hook like this:

```js
const App = () => {
  const myRef = useRef()
   
  useEffect(()=>{
    myRef.current.classList.toggle() // and more..
  })
  
  return(
    <div> 
      <h1 ref={ref}>element you want toggle</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```